# How to make all items in a div equal width without text wrapping?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a row of three buttons, where all the buttons are equal width.
If the width of the screen gets smaller, the buttons should shrink to fit the screen.
Once the text starts to wrap on any of the buttons, I want to switch the orientation of the buttons from horizontal to vertical.

I have tried to achieve this with flex box.

Here is what I have so far:

```
button {
background: black;
font-size: 1.2em;
width: 32%;
color: white;
padding-top: 11px;
padding-bottom: 11px;
padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
border-radius: 100px;
min-width: min-content;
white-space: nowrap; 
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.btn-containter{
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  align-content: stretch;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}



<div class="btn-container">
  <button onclick=test  type="button">button with long text</button>
  <button onclick=test  type="button">button with really really long text</button>
  <button onclick=test  type="button">button with text</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd need javascript to have a way of triggering an event to change your layout when text wrapping occurs to get the result you're after.

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is ***not*** needed for this. You should use [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and the more modern [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to achieve this.

```css
button {
background: black;

width: 100%;

font-size: 20px;
color: white;
text-align: center;

padding-top: 11px;
padding-bottom: 11px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-right: 20px;

border-radius: 100px;

white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "button1 button2 button3";
  width: 100vw;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   .btn-container {
      grid-template-areas: "button1"
                  "button2"
                  "button3";
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button onclick=test style="grid-area: button1" type="button">button with long text</button>
  <button onclick=test style="grid-area: button2" type="button">button with really really long text</button>
  <button onclick=test style="grid-area: button3" type="button">button with text</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you  misspelled the class name of the `.btn-container`.Then  change flex-direction to column and remove `align-items:stretch` and `justify-content:stretch`.

Then remove the button `width:32%`.

check it now it works fine

```css
button {
background: black;
font-size: 1.2em;
color: white;
padding-top: 11px;
padding-bottom: 11px;
padding-left: 20px;
   padding-right: 20px;
border-radius: 100px;
min-width: min-content;
white-space: nowrap; 
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-grow: 1;
flex-basis: 0;
text-align: center;
}

.btn-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button onclick=test  type="button">button with long text</button>
  <button onclick=test  type="button">button with really really long text</button>
  <button onclick=test  type="button">button with text</button>
</div>
```